# How to use iframe component in solidjs?

Tags: javascript, iframe, solid-js

I would like to insert an iframe in my solidjs application. For this I downloaded the [iframe package](https://www-npmjs-com.translate.goog/package/iframe?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=op,sc) . But it rather created a bug in my application. Here is the code of my iframe:

```
import Iframe from 'iframe'
export default function SearchEngine() {
    return (

    <div>
          <Iframe src="http://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com"  width="100%" height="657px" />
     </div>

    )

}
```

I would like to know how to insert an iframe in solidjs. I wonder if there is a module like [react-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-iframe) for solidjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any special package for inserting iframes for solid. But do you need some special features that react-iframe provided, or is it simply to have an [iframe HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) on the page?

Because you can just use lowercase `<iframe>` element normally, and build any additional functionality you need on top of it.

```
export default function SearchEngine() {
   return (
      <div>
         <iframe src="http://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com"  width="100%" height="657px"/>
      </div>
   )
}
```

[Playground demo](https://playground.solidjs.com/?hash=-1863989872&version=1.4.1)